# iOS Xcode 6.2 Full Screen - Run Crash

Tags: ios, xcode

Has anyone experienced XCode crashing if you have it in Full Screen View and then try to run an app to a connected device?

I am experiencing this roughly 50% of the time when I am running my app to a connected iPad. I am using Xcode 6.2

Comment: I'm gonna take a wild guess here and say that it doesn't actually crash, but it _closes_ the window [due to a bug](https://twitter.com/jose_ibanez/status/540227479278215168). Workaround: Try to run with command+R instead

Comment: The workaround appears to be working. I need to get in the habit of using command+R anyways.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that it's crashing, but it's executing the red close button every time you run it.

I've seen the same thing. Use Command-R, or move your mouse to the top of the screen so that the bar comes down,then you can run it.